# Getting values of other components in aem

Tags: javascript, dialog, components, sightly, aem-6

I have created 2 components (component A, component B) and 2 pages(page A,page B) in AEM 6.4. I have added component A to page A and component B to page B. My requirement is to display the value authored in page A to page B. How can I achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is fixed then you could just use [`data-sly-resource`](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#229-resource) to include the component B node from Page B to page A.

Assuming:

```
/content/mysite/pageA/jcr:content/root/container/componentA
/content/mysite/pageB/jcr:content/root/footer/componentB
```

You could do (in `componentA`'s HTL script):

```
<sly data-sly-resource="/content/mysite/pageB/jcr:content/root/footer/componentB"></sly>
```

**However**, if you want to share editable content between multiple pages, your should really use [Experience Fragments](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/sites/experience-fragments/experience-fragments-feature-video-use.html?lang=en#experience-fragments-full-text-search). They're reusable editable component blocks and the [Core Components Experience Fragment component](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/tree/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/experiencefragment/v1/experiencefragment#features) also allows using the same localization as you current page (especially useful when using the Experience Fragment in the header/footer of your page template). See also the [WKND tutorial examples](https://github.com/adobe/aem-guides-wknd/tree/master/ui.content.sample/src/main/content/jcr_root/content/experience-fragments/wknd)!